# SharePoint 2013 "Start a Task Process" Overdue frequency Hourly

Tags: workflow

Can we add "Hourly" into the OverDue Repeat values in sharepoint 2013 Workflow Start a task process action. I need the overdue emails sent every 2 hours until the task gets approved. Is there any way to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow with a loop, in this loop insert a command "waiting to" and set to date + 2 hours, then send e-mail.

If the task is completed, end the loop. Else, enter in loop.